# How to manipulate OnClick method on my React App?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to create a basic react app which contains 4 Reactstrap Card Items and now I want this functionality where when I click at one of the cards, the clicked card gets copied all the way at the end of the page and we display additional information related to the card.

Here is one of the component code-

```
import React,{useState} from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import {Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody,
    CardTitle} from "reactstrap";

function MenuComponent (props){

return (
    
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
          
        {props.dishes.map((dish)=>{
           return (
          <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
            <Card key={dish.id} >
            <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
            </Card>
          </div>
           );
        }
        )
        }
        
      
    </div>
    </div>

);

}
    

export default MenuComponent;
```

Here is the Dishes array of objects having the details about the dish-

```
Dishes=[
    {
      id: 0,
      name:'Uthappizza',
      image: 'asset/images/uthappizza.png',
      category: 'mains',
      label:'Hot',
      price:'4.99',
      description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'                        },
   {
      id: 1,
      name:'Zucchipakoda',
      image: 'asset/images/zucchipakoda.png',
      category: 'appetizer',
      label:'',
      price:'1.99',
      description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce'                        },
   {
      id: 2,
      name:'Vadonut',
      image: 'asset/images/vadonut.png',
      category: 'appetizer',
      label:'New',
      price:'1.99',
      description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?'                        },
   {
      id: 3,
      name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
      image: 'asset/images/elaicheesecake.png',
      category: 'dessert',
      label:'',
      price:'2.99',
      description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms'                        }
   ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to copy the content of a dish, it's possible to use this lib https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-to-clipboard in this way.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import {
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardImgOverlay,
  CardText,
  CardBody,
  CardTitle,
} from "reactstrap";
import copy from "copy-to-clipboard";

function MenuComponent(props) {
  const copyHandler = (dish) => {
    copy(dish.name);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        {props.dishes.map((dish) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
              <Card key={dish.id} onClick={() => copyHandler(dish)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                <CardImgOverlay>
                  <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
                </CardImgOverlay>
              </Card>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MenuComponent;
```

But if you need to get a new copy of the element, the best choice would be to receive the setState function for props and execute in a handler like in the example above or apply the dishes in the component's state.